# How to understand the proposed resolution of #1664

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

After looking at the proposed resolution of #1664([proposed resolution 1664](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1664)), I'm confused for the rules of a default argument of a function template, Cite the content here:

### According to 8.1.5 [expr.prim.lambda] paragraph 3

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains 
>      the corresponding lambda-expression. [Note: This determines the set of namespaces and classes associated with the closure type (6.4.2 [basic.lookup.argdep]). The parameter types of a lambda- 
>      declarator do not affect these associated namespaces and classes. —end note]

### However, 17.8.1 [temp.inst] paragraph 13 says

> If a function template f is called in a way that requires a default argument to be used, the dependent names are looked up, the semantics constraints are checked, and the instantiation of any template used in the default argument is done as if the default argument had been an initializer used in a function template specialization with the same scope, the same template parameters and the same access as that of the function template f used at that point.

A possibility, then, is that the closure type for lambda expression in a default argument for a template function (or, presumably, a member function of a class template) is to be considered as having been declared in some block scope in the body of the fictional function template specialization.

#### Consider the following example:

```cpp
 namespace J {
    inline namespace K {
      template <typename T> int zap(const T &t) { foo(t); return 0; }
      template <typename T> void zip(int = zap([] { })) { }
    }
    template <typename T> void foo(const T &) { }
  }
  void bar() { 
    J::K::zip<long>(); 
    /*Accroding to the above wording,the invoke just like:  
      => J::K::zip<long>(zap([] { })); 
   */
  }
```

> If zip were not a template, argument-dependent lookup successfully resolves the lookup for foo in all implementations tested; however, there is implementation variance in the handling of the example as written.

### Proposed resolution (September 2013):

> Change 17.8.1 [temp.inst] paragraph 13 as follows:
>   If a function template f is called in a way that requires a default argument to be used, the dependent names are looked up, the semantics constraints are checked, and the instantiation of any template used in the default argument is done as if the default argument had been an initializer used in a function template specialization with the same scope, the same template parameters and the same access as that of the function template f used at that point, **except that the scope in which a closure type is declared (8.1.5 [expr.prim.lambda]) — and therefore its associated namespaces — remain as determined from the context of the definition for the default argument**. This analysis is called default argument instantiation. The instantiated default argument is then used as the argument of f.

Note the emphasized part,if I do not misunderstand,It means if the emphasized part comment out,the `foo` could not  be looked up by **argument dependent look up** because the argument `[] { }` which namespace is neither `J` nor `K`,assume the form within `function bar` like `J::K::zip<long>(zap([] { }) /*default argument*/);`,So accroding to **[expr.prim.lambda] paragraph 3** the namespace of `[] { }` is at `fuction bar` and at that scope,there's no `foo` can be found,So the emphasized part is for this case that consider the namespace of `[] { }` within `zap` as the same as `zap`,it means the namespace of `[] { }` is `K`,Now the `foo` can be found in the parent namespace `J` by argument dependent  lookup rules ,So far ,If i misundertand these rules,please correct me.the other point view is that the default argument is evaluated every time when the function called,even if the default is **non-dependent**.So continue consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A {

};
template<typename T>
int func(T, float) {  //#a
    std::cout << "float" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
template<typename T>
void test(int = func(A{}, 0)) { //#1

}
template<typename T>
int func(T, int) {  //#b
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    test<A>(); //#2 transform to: test<A>(func(A{}, 0)); here,#b should be the best match
    std::getchar();
}
```

Although the default argument `func` is non-dependent,However it should be determined every time when the function `test` is called and I test the code in some compliers.
All the version of MSVC report "int",gcc report "float",clang report "float",what's the hell?Accroding to the report of gcc or clang,It seems to the `func` is determined at `#1`and MSVC proved that the `func` is determined at `#2`. if MSVC is wrong ,that means the non-dependent default argument could be determined within #1 and it's unnecessary to determine every time when the function called,why the emphasized part need to add?(**If I understand the emphasized part correctly,the purpose of it is that keep the namespace of closure type within default argument consistent whether the lambda-expression is at the point of function declaration or the point of call**). If I misunderstand these rules,How to interpret them correctly?

### UPDATE:

the version 9.1 or higher of gcc can not complie the code mentioned in #1664,it will report error ([the complie result](https://godbolt.org/z/H-ywdp))

### Questions:

1.Does the non-dependent default argument of function template or non-template function need to determined every time when the corresponding function called?

2.what does "the definition for the default argument" mean?Is this wording strictly?(**In other word,my understanding is,what actullay the added rules want to express is that the namespace of closeure type is that of a function declartion where contain a default argument which contain the corresponding lambda-expression,Right?if my understanding about this is wrong,correct me**)

Comment: "same scope ... as that of the function template `f` used" actually sounds like the hypothetical specialization would be within namespace `J::K`, not within the definition of `bar`, but then I don't see how the changed phrase would make any difference.

Comment: I understand all that, but I don't think we concluded the same thing from the wording before the changed / bolded part.

Comment: "Now,I start a bounty for additional question." This is not how StackOverflow works. If you have a new question, ask a new question. One question per question. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Barry  I think the updated question belong to "How to understand the proposed resolution of #1664"

Comment: Sorry, you need to post *new questions*. Stack Overflow is here to build a repository of useful questions and their answers *for future visitors*, and now that your first question has an answer we view this page as a single whole. Please respect the work that the answerer has put into the providing with a solution and put new questions into new question posts. Altering (expanding) the problem here would otherwise invalidate their answer and make your post *off topic* (closed as “needs more focus”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments are **evaluated** every time they are called, but this is a runtime property: calls are counted not by source line but by actual control flow.  Separately, a default argument for a templated function is [considered to be a definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.decls#2.sentence-1) and is **instantiated** when needed, up to once per **specialization** of the function (with the usual proviso about multiple points of instantiation that must agree).  CWG1664 was a very narrow issue based on how that instantiation was *worded*: by introducing a **fictitious** function template, it left open the possibility that the lambda’s declaration “physically” moved.  The fix really does affect only ADL.

Your `func` example instead illustrates the usual name-lookup rules in templates: no matter how many times and *whence* `test`’s default argument is instantiated, `func` in it is not a **dependent** name and thus finds `func(T,float)` (every time).  **MSVC** has famously never implemented this rule correctly (because, to be fair, their implementation predates the rule and they’ve only recently started the requisite (and nearly complete) rewrite of their template support).

Meanwhile, recent GCC is plainly buggy with the CWG1664 example: note that it complains about `foo` being used but not defined, **contradicting** both the plainly visible `{ }` and its prior error message about not finding it.

Comment: I try to summarize my understanding about your answers.1. For default argument,if they are non-dependent names,the names are bound as written at that point(as [dcl.fct.default]/5 said ),instead, the dependent names are necessary to lookup name every time when the function called. 2.For a lambda-expression ,because it's not a name,so it can not be bound even if the default argument is non-dependent,so if there's no emphasized part to constraint,the closeure type would have different namespace accroding to the point of call where the namespace cover it.Do you agree?

Comment: Another question from your answers i need to talk individually is,Does "fictional function template specialization" refer to  "J::K::zip<long>(); "  ,rather than the definiton of "J::K::zip<long>()" at point of instantiation?

Comment: @jackX: It’s that and [temp.nondep]/1 for non-dependent names; dependent names are looked up for every **instantiation** whether or not they appear in a default argument.  The closure type would belong to the fictitious function template specialization (which is neither a call nor any actual definition of `zip`).

Comment: so ,the "the fictitious function template specialization" refer to something like "J::K::zip<long>(); "? and what is the effective of " except that the scope in which a closure type is declared",I think the sentence followed it :"and therefore its associated namespaces — remain as determined from the context of the definition for the default argument" is enough to ADL

Comment: @jackX: I just said that it didn’t so refer.  The scope is the actual rule: the namespaces are a corollary, even if they carry all the import.

Comment: But,I have to say that constraints the namespace of closure type  is enough  for ADL to lookup the unqualified function `foo`,I just kind of don't understand the sentence "except that the scope in which a closure type is declare"

Comment: @jackX: This is (now) a question of English, not C++; the sentence just makes more sense phrased the way it is, and doesn’t tamper with distant name-lookup rules (the way that too many do).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209776/discussion-between-jack-x-and-davis-herring).